# Using Laravel 4 on a subdomain - subdomains in general

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4, subdomain

I am building an application for my company who use Perl as the language of the company. I'm thinking of adding my Laravel application to a subdomain of the domain which the company uses.

This question is really just out of precaution: if I create a folder for my application i.e. myproject.example.com and initialise Laravel in there, would pointing my routes to start with the subdomain be sufficient? I don't want the main site to end up pointing to my `/` route lol!

Also Laravel comes with its own .htaccess setup; if my application is in myproject.example.com, will that have any effect on the main site (www.example.com)?

Comment: I think Laravel respect conf file app.php. what  the config url variable is  ? didn't try it before .

Comment: @JohnTaa the url key is set to http://myproject.example.com

Comment: Doesn't subdomain imply different web root, more or less? If your laravel app is in a different root than the perl app, there should be no issue.